# how to get the sum form query result

Tags: mysql

Here is my query. I want to get the sum from reqery result.

```
SELECT COUNT( user_id ) c
FROM mst_tabs
WHERE merchant_id =3
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING c >1
```

This is my query result.I am trying to get the summation of this result.

```
    c 
--------    
    19
    3
    26
    93
    20
    2
    34
    5
```

I don't know how to use sum() with this result.

Comment: `select sum(c) from ( your current query here )x` and dont forget that `x`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I was about to comment the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(c)
FROM (SELECT COUNT( user_id ) as c
      FROM mst_tabs
      WHERE merchant_id =3
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING c > 1 
     ) c;
```

If you have a unique id in each row, then you can do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.user_id ) as c
FROM mst_tabs m
WHERE merchant_id = 3 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM mst_tabs m2
              WHERE m2.merchant_id = m.merchant_id AND
                    m2.user_id = m.user_id AND m.id <> m2.id);
```

This may be faster with an index on `mst_abs(merchant_id, user_id, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum( c )
FROM (

SELECT COUNT( user_id ) c
FROM mst_tabs
WHERE merchant_id =3
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING c >1
) AS t
```

Here I have created an alias for table. Then get the sum of that result.